# nginx proxy_pass based on whether request method is POST, PUT or DELETE

Tags: lua, nginx

I have two [iKaaro](http://hforge.org/ikaaro) instances running on port 8080 and 9080, where the 9080 instance is Read only.

I am unsure how to use nginx for example if the request method is POST, PUT, DELETE then send to write instance (8080) else send to 9080 instance.

I have done something using the location using the regex, but this is not correct.

From http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule i see that there is the 'HTTP method constants' which can be called, so is it correct to add a location block as:

```
location ~* "(ngx.HTTP_POST|ngx.HTTP_DELETE|ngx.HTTP_PUT)" {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain the question a bit better? Have you tried that setup? Are you having any errors with it (which ones)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I just did a quick test, and this worked for me:

```
server {
  location / {
    # This proxy_pass is used for requests that don't
    # match the limit_except
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;

    limit_except PUT POST DELETE {
      # For requests that *aren't* a PUT, POST, or DELETE,
      # pass to :9080
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it also doesn't rely on any third party modules

Comment: This is pretty confusing, first you say `don't match the limit_except` and before the limit_except you say `aren't`, so if I have a `GET` request, it does not match the `limit_except` (so `8080` according to the comment), but also `GET` is not "a PUT, POST, or DELETE", so `9080`

Comment: I've moved the second comment into the limit_except block.  Does that make it clearer for you which requests will be handled by that inner block, and not the outer proxy_pass?

Answer (score 12):

I assume you got the basics in place. I.E., you have installed Lua 5.1, or better still, LuaJIT 2.0, on your server, compiled Nginx with the ngx_lua module and configured ngx_lua as required.

With that in place, This will do the job:

```
location /test {
    content_by_lua '
        local reqType = ngx.var.request_method
        if reqType == ngx.HTTP_POST 
            OR reqType == ngx.HTTP_DELETE 
            OR reqType == ngx.HTTP_PUT 
        then
            res = ngx.location.capture("/write_instance")
        else
            res = ngx.location.capture("/read_instance")
        end
        ngx.say(res.body)
    ';
}
location /write_instance {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
location /read_instance {
    internal;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;
}
```

***UPDATE***

I thought perhaps you were specifically using Lua in a larger scope. The example below would also work on the same principle as limit_except.

```
location /test {
    if ($request_method !~* GET) {
        # For Write Requests
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    # For Read Requests
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9080;
}
```

Both "if" and "limit_except" block effectively create a nested location block and once the condition matches, only the content handler ("proxy_pass") of the inner location block thus created will be executed.

Not fully getting this is why if is sometimes said to be "evil" but in this case the "evil" behaviour, common to both "if" and "limit_except", may be exactly what you want.

So three choices for you to pick from!

Note however that you will have to watch that you don't get bitten by the "evil" behaviour with either of the "if" or "limit_except" options if you need to set any other directives.

I.E., if you set a directive inside the "if" or "limit_except" block, it may not be active outside it and similarly, something set outside may be inherited inside. So you have to watch how defaults are inherited, or not, as the case may be, with both approaches.

All the potential issues listed on the [If is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) page apply equally to "if" and "limit_except" here. The Lua based scripting approach will avoid many of those potential pitfalls as suggested on that page.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the detailed explantation, so i need to take care if the IfiSEvil should i need to run other directives.
I may need to as i also need to include specific URL such as location ~* "(login|new_content)" { ... but i will try to figure it out and come back here with my nginx.conf file to see if it can be improved.

Comment: Try to separate the queries by specific issue. I assume that with the three options you have, the specific question on how route requests in Nginx based on the request method has been answered exhaustively. You can either you "if" directly or "limit_except" which is a type of if statement bearing the potential issues in mind, or use a scripting method such as the Lua example given to avoid these issues. You might want to consider accepting one or the other of the answers given and asking a new question if there are other issues.

Comment: This was an informative response.  I'm trying to use your first solution (the `content_by_lua` approach), but I'm noticing that the call to `ngx.say(res.body)` does not include the headers from the response object, just the body.  How can I get the response's headers to be written to the final ngx response?

Answer (score 7):

I'd recommend the nginx map function.  This goes outside of your location block:

```
map $request_method $destination {
    default 8080;
    PUT 9080;
    POST 9080;
    DELETE 9080;
}
```

Then in your location block:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:$destination
```

This is all regexes too, so you can do things like:

```
map $request_method $cookie_auth $destination {
    default 8080;
    "^POST " 9080;
    "^PUT someAuthCookieValue" 9080;
}
```

Plus this avoids the use of if at all.  It's pretty awesome.  I used it to direct all write traffic in a WordPress cluster to one FastCGI TCP socket on a remote node but send read traffic to a local FastCGI UNIX socket.

Comment: I wonder why this one get so few votes actually being the best answer yet.

Comment: However second example given incorrectly, regex usage is defined by `~` string prefix, the correct equivalent is `map "$request_method:$cookie_auth" $destination { default 8080; "~^POST:" 9080; "~^PUT:someAuthCookieValue$" 9080; }`

Answer (score 2):

In case someone looking for a way to simply make conditions by request method, the syntax is:

```
if ($request_method = DELETE ) {
   . . . 
}
```

Comment: ..although, I have to mention, that using IF in config is not recommended by nginx team: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil