# Nginx proxy_pass based on POST/GET/PUT/DELETE parameter

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to configure nginx to do a `proxy_pass` based on a POST/GET/PUT/DELETE parameter in my request.

I want to `proxy_pass` to `http://10.0.0.2:8000` if `live=1` or to `http://10.0.0.2:8081` if `live=0`.

I tried using `if ($arg_live = "1")` but it only works for GET requests.

Thanks,

Pedro

Comment: I had the same issue, I believe you'd need to parse $request_body for POST but somehow it is very tricky when that is set

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx proxy\_pass based on whether request method is POST, PUT or DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8591600/nginx-proxy-pass-based-on-whether-request-method-is-post-put-or-delete)

Comment: For future visitors, this is more than vanilla Nginx can handle on its own.  Look into using Nginx's Lua module.  OpenResty makes it easy to get the module installed.  There's also a module that offers $post_* variables, though Lua is still a better fit for complex logic like this.

Comment: At least as of nginx 1.14 request parameter from the request like `PUT /some/route?live=1 HTTP/1.1` is detected correctly, `$arg_live` nginx variable gets populated with the correct value. Analyzing the request body is another subject and really better to be done with some third party module, however detecting some string presence via the `map` block is possible too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try this..

```
if ($request_method = 'POST') {
 #your_directives_here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if ($arg_live = "0"){
        rewrite ^ /live1 last;
    }
    if ($arg_live = "1") {
        rewrite ^ /live0 last;
    }
    location /live0/ {
        proxy_pass http://live0-server;
    }
    location /live1/ {
        proxy_pass http://live1-server;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.